# Similarity between the mathematics used in PDEs and in image processing

Tags: partial-differential-equations, soft-question, signal-processing, image-processing

<sub>Sorry if this question is a bit vague</sub>

I took a course on PDEs and learned or reviewed a lot of math revolving around Fourier transforms, convolutions, distributions, Gaussian functions, etc, all simply in the context of solving PDEs. I later took another course, this time on image processing (which was moreover in the neuroscience department rather than mathematics) and was quite surprised to see the same mathematics pop up: we used Fourier transforms, convolutions, the Dirac delta distribution, and Gaussian functions, but now all entirely in the context of transforming signals/images and highlighting different features of them.

It seems strange to me that the same mathematics and so much of it should pop up in two very different subjects - at least on the surface level there doesn't seem to be much connection at all between PDEs and signal processing. I was wondering if anyone has some sort of explanation on how they are somehow connected, or why the same mathematics pops up.

Comment: 1) In signal processing, it is mainly for solving **ODE**, PDE also but more rarely. 2) You have underlined the common tools/approaches, the main diffrence now being that In the first case it is 1D whereas in the second it is 2D.

Comment: Imagine processing has a lot of connections to PDEs. Indeed, there is an entire book on the subject. See Aubert, G., Kornprobst, P., & Aubert, G. (2006). Mathematical problems in image processing: partial differential equations and the calculus of variations (Vol. 147, p. 26). New York: Springer.

Comment: @whpowell96 I didn't say anything about PDEs for image processing, just for (1D) signal processing...

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Variational PDE models
in image processing](https://www.ams.org/journals/notices/200301/fea-shen-03.pdf) [PDF] (2003)